# VPN configuration: shared secret PSK format

Tags: linux, vpn, apple, strongswan

I am using, as a customer, a commercial VPN for OS/X and iPhone. I am also [provisioning VNPs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255876/mac-os-sierra-ignoring-vpn-mobile-profile) at work for iOS/MacOs, and have a Debian based VPN at home with StrongSwan.

I have captured the `.mobileconfig` provisioning file the  Sierra MacOS executable provided by my VPN provider generates. I would like to get the configuration details from there, in order to not install their Linux software and configure it manually, however the SharedSecret XML data field is encrypted.

At work, I have been using `Apple Configurator 2`, just to encrypt my Shared Secret for creating the skeleton of mobileconfig provisioning files for Apple devices, however I still do not have any idea what is the format  of that field.

I have noticed this "encrypted" password can be placed in `ipsec.secrets`, in lieu of the clear text passwords, such as:

```
@vpngroup : PSK 0scGFzc3dvcmQK
```

Likewise, again in Apple mobileconfig provision files that are delivered to customers/end users, it can be found again:

```
<key>SharedSecret</key>
<data>cGFzc3dvcmQK</data>
```

So what actually is this format? And how to encrypt and encrypt it? I know for sure it is not the actual Shared Secret in clear text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the enconding of Shared Secret/ group password is actually [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

From the [strongswan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/PskSecret) documentation site:

> Alternatively, preshared secrets can be represented as hexadecimal or
>   Base64 encoded binary values. A character sequence beginning with 0x
>   is interpreted as sequence hexadecimal digits. Similarly, a character
>   sequence beginning with 0s is interpreted as Base64 encoded binary
>   data.

The Base64 format for the group password, besides being used in Linux/FreeBSD IPsec configurations and Apple provisioning files, is also used in Cisco VPN client files.

The justification for the use of Base64 is to protect the password from prying eyes and the end users. Why using then such a basic encoding algorithm...

At the end of the day, to decode it in Linux, it has to be taken verbatim from the Apple SharedSecret data field, or when being taken from `ipsec.secrets`, you have to ignore the leading "0s" from the string:

```
$echo cGFzc3dvcmQK | base64 -d
password
```

To decode it in FreeBSD/OS/X:

```
$echo cGFzc3dvcmQK | base64 -D
password
```

Likewise, to encode it back:

```
$echo password | base64
cGFzc3dvcmQK
```